# Is there a good place for proposing new open source projects?

Tags: open-source

Is there a decent website or service out there where developers can propose a new idea for an open source project (regardless of language) and have the community vote it up / down, form teams, and do everything that precedes writing the first line of code?

Comment: Why dont you try to propose one in area 51 stackexchange
http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ckv - area51 is for stack exchange ideas, not open source project ideas.

Comment: @Oded: he means to propose a new stackexchange site about proposing new open source projects

Comment: I'll propose one at Area51 - that sounds like an excellent idea.

Comment: Here we go: FOSS BrainStorm on Area51:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11609/foss-brainstorm?referrer=51D_1y7Php0KPXt__KHbjg2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of like Kickstarter (for funding), SourceForge (for hosting), or an IdeaStorm (for brainstorming and community feedback)?   The Apache Foundation, or the Horde project (for incubating a plethora of related projects)?  It really depends on to what your idea relates.  Try joining one of the relevant extant open-source communities and sounding off on your idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [SomeBodyMakeThis reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/SomebodyMakeThis). Also, project sites like SourceForge allow you to create a project which is in the "planning" stage. Often, this is used by people who think they have a good idea and want somebody else to make it for them.